# Does node.exe for Windows have an option to specify environment variables?

Tags: node.js

The `node` project I need to run requires certain environment variables.

It runs on Windows, and it works fine when I try:

```
set MY_ENV=abc & node .
```

Is there an option in `node.exe` itself that can be used instead of this?

Because there are cases where I can't use the & symbol.

I'm wondering if an option similar to the following exists:

```
node . --env MY_ENV=abc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't. You can use a batch script or a shell script to set the environment variables before executing the node command.
for example:

```
@echo off
set MY_ENV=abc
node .
```